# Oracle Database Deployment using Microsoft Release Management

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

I have some question about release management tool.

Can  release management tool used for oracle database?

How to deploy Oracle Database scripts to the Oracle using Microsoft Release Management Tool?

Is there any documentation about using release management tool for oracle scripts?

And has release management tool  some internal features for oracle deployments?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

TFS Release Management doesn't have any out of the box tool for deploying Oracle scripts.

But you can create your own tool/script to be used within Release Management. Anything you can run from command line can be used with Release Management.